# How to use json body parser in Security trait

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.2

I'm new to play and scala so it's hard to figure out some basic stuff. What I'm tryig to implement is api authentication. To accomplish it I implemented the similar auth action like Security trait in zentask example.

But when I'm trying to access json body of request in security trait i got compiler error saying ; "value \ is not a member of type parameter A"

here is the auth action ;

```
def withApiAuth[A](bp: BodyParser[A])(f: Request[A] => Result): Action[A] = {
        Action(bp) { request =>
            val chargeJson = request.body
            val appId:Option[String] = (chargeJson \ "appid").asOpt[String]

            if(appId.isDefined){
                Logger.info("Api request" + appId)
                f(request)
            }
            else{
                Results.BadRequest("unfortunately")
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm using it in controller like this;

```
def pay = withApiAuth(parse.json){ request =>

        val chargeJson = request.body

        println(chargeJson)

        Ok("helo")
    }
```

What I'm missing?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to accomplish with `withApiAuth`. You're getting that compile error because the compiler doesn't know that the body parser is json in `withApiAuth`. If your intention is to pass json with every request, then the body parser shouldn't be a parameter, but that is going to severely limit the usage of that function.

Comment: actually i want to accomplish is, all actions with composed withApiAuth should be json content http request. and also should include an application id in the body. So that I don't need to implement those in each action again and again. I want to have reusable action block which accept only json request and provide a simple auth mechanism.

Comment: You can replace `bp: BodyParser[A]` with parse.json, since you only want the body parser to be json. This will of course prevent you from using POST forms or any other request body. And it isn't a remotely secure form of authentication.

Comment: thanks man that actually worked. post it as an anwser so i can mark it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

request.body is not quite enough.  You need to do request.body.asJson so that chargeJson is the correct type.

val chargeJson = request.body
val appId:Option[String] = (chargeJson \ "appid").asOpt[String]

Comment: request.body would be enough using a body parser.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `bp: BodyParser[A]` with `parse.json`. Since you only want the body of the request to be json, it should be fixed body parser. Otherwise the json api won't know with any certainty that request.body is expected to be json.